# Get the latest duplicates/triplicates from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, reduce

I have an array and want to know which ones are duplicate/triplicate or more.

Example: get the latest item only when it shows up 3 times or more.

Input:

```
const items = [
  {id: 3, date: new Date('2020/8/3')},
  {id: 1, date: new Date('2020/8/1')},
  {id: 1, date: new Date('2020/8/4')},
  {id: 1, date: new Date('2020/8/2')},
  {id: 2, date: new Date('2020/8/1')},
  {id: 2, date: new Date('2020/8/4')},
  {id: 3, date: new Date('2020/8/3')},
  {id: 3, date: new Date('2020/8/4')},
  {id: 1, date: new Date('2020/8/3')},
]
```

Now id 1 shows up 4 times, id 2 does 2 times and id 3 does 3 times. I want the latest id 1 and the latest id 3.

Output:

```
const frequentItems = [
  {id: 3, date: new Date('2020/8/4')},
  {id: 1, date: new Date('2020/8/4')},
]
```

Do you know the easiest, simplest and efficient way to do it?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: My idea was to create intermediate ```const counted``` to be ```{1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 3}```, then reduce orderd by date items and check if it's in ```counts```, then find the latest. I feel there are much better way to do it.

Comment: Why is item with id=2 not appearing in the output? _Edit: Oh, I see! You keep changing the question..._

Comment: Do you want items that show up 2 or more times, or 3 or more times? Do you want to find `id`s that are present at least that many times, or *values* that are present at least that many times?

Comment: I want to find items that show up ***n*** times or more (***n*** can be 2 or 3). I edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: I believe you output for id=1 is incorrect; shouldn't latest be `2020/8/4`?

Comment: @Luka Sorry, you are right. I fixed it.

Comment: Good. Now you can check the answers, and accept the only correct one, if you feel so ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best possible runtime is O(n) which is to use a [count sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) like algorithm with a little O(n) extra memory space; check out the snippet below

```js
const items = [
  {id: 3, date: new Date('2020/8/3')},
  {id: 1, date: new Date('2020/8/1')},
  {id: 1, date: new Date('2021/8/2')},
  {id: 2, date: new Date('2020/8/1')},
  {id: 2, date: new Date('2020/8/4')},
  {id: 3, date: new Date('2022/8/3')},
  {id: 3, date: new Date('2020/8/4')},
  {id: 1, date: new Date('2020/8/3')},
];

// used to keep track of repetition number of each id;
const itemCount = Object.create(null);
// used to random access each object by its key later;
const keyIndexedObjects = Object.create(null);

items.forEach( item => {
  const currentItemDate = new Date( item.date );
  const prevoiusItemDate = new Date( (keyIndexedObjects[item.id]||{}).date);

  // only update key index object if its date is bigger than prevoius date
  if(!(prevoiusItemDate &&
  (prevoiusItemDate > currentItemDate))){
    keyIndexedObjects[item.id] = item;
  }
  
  itemCount[item.id] = (itemCount[item.id] || 0) + 1;
});

const desiredOutput = [];

for ( const [key, value] of Object.entries(itemCount) ){
  if( value >= 3 ) desiredOutput.push(keyIndexedObjects[key])
}

console.log(desiredOutput)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop two times through the items: first time to remember counts of each item (in object `counts` in the code below) and remember the latest of each item (object `latest`), and second time to collect only those that count more than twice.

```js
let counts = {};
let latest = {};
for(let x of items) {
    if(!counts[x.id]) counts[x.id] = 0;
    counts[x.id]++;
    if(!latest[x.id] || latest[x.id].date < x.date) latest[x.id] = x;
}

let frequentItems  = [];
for(let id in counts) {
    if(counts[id] > 2) frequentItems.push(latest[id]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also make use of the [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

It by definition does/should not contain duplicate item.

1. Create a new Set

`let dataSet = new Set()`

2.Iterate through the data and add the id of items into the set

`dataSet.add(item.id)`

3. The resulting dataSet will contain the id that are unique

Comment: this is not what OP asked